# how to pass additional parameter in the url using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I pass additional parameter in the url for pagination to work

my existing page link is `http://localhost/site/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myPage`

how do i create the syntax / logic in **PHP** to add `&pagenum=1` in the url?

currently i have this code

```
global $wpdb;

$per_page = 6;
$page_query = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM form"); 

$pages = ceil($page_query / $per_page);

$currentPage = (isset ($_GET['pagenum'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagenum'] : 1;
$start = ($currentPage -1 ) * $per_page;

$row = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM form LIMIT $start , $per_page");

//foreach loop here
```

Comment: Just add `&pagenum=1` at the end of the url in `href`

Comment: That's what I thought, but I can't believe someone would post such a trivial question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pagenum = 1;
$url = "http://localhost/site/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myPage" . "&pagenum=".$pagenum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

First build an array of data you want to transfer like--

```
$data=array(
 "param1"=>"value1",
 "param2"=>"value2"
);
```

Then use `http_build_query`to convert data to url format!!

```
$url_data=http_build_query($data);
$target_url="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // your url here
if(strpos($target_url,"?")==false){
   $target_url.="?";
}else{
   $target_url.="&";
}
$target_url.=$url_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$page='MyPage';
$pagenum = 1;
$url = "http://localhost/site/wp-admin/admin.php?page=".$page."&pagenum=".$pagenum;
```